# Needed Help In Design Layout (CSS)

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I am having a problem regarding some layout design tasks. Actually I want to achieve a certain layout design, but since I don't quite understand the position property of CSS, it's a bit difficult for me to do this. Here's the [link to what i am actually trying to do](http://aligator-studio.com/cypress/product-category/mens-clothing/).

I want an area or container whose position will be fixed as designed in above mention linked. In this web layout design, the left side of the web page is `position: fixed`: it's not moving and when i scroll the right side of the page it is scrolling down. So i need the same functioning for my web page.

(Sorry for my bad English i am little bit passive at it)

Answer (score 0):

For that you use the `position:fixed` attribute in your CSS.
You would make a sidebar that does not scroll like this:
HTML

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
This is fixed to the side of the page!
</div>
<div id="main">This Scrolls!</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:400px;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
#main{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:lightblue;
text-align:center;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterHappy/Na49u/)